# AngularJS - how to display a custom text in a disabled textbox

Tags: validation, angularjs

I have the following input control:

```
<input type="ng-model="someValue" ng-disabled="shouldBeDisabled"/>
```

and a model with following variables:

- `someValue` - the value that should be displayed in INPUT when `shouldBeDisabled==fals`
- `shouldBeDisabled` - if the INPUT should be disabled
- `disabledText` - the text that should be displays in INPUT instead of `someValue` when `shouldBeDisabled==true`

How should I change the above HTML slipet to implement this with AngularJS?
Is it possible to implement this with build-in AngularJS directives with just these three model variables? Or do I need to introduce another variables (such as `someValueForInputBox`) and take care to synchonizing it with `someValue` (when not disabled) or `disabledText` (when disabled)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by the following though you might want to put a watch on `shouldBeDisabled`;

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.shouldBeDisabled = true;

  $scope.toggleIt = function() {
    $scope.shouldBeDisabled= ! $scope.shouldBeDisabled;
    $scope.someValue= $scope.shouldBeDisabled && $scope.disabledText  || "true value"; // modify as required or leave off the true part.
  }
});
```

You could also store the value so when the disabled text comes up and then toggles back you can repopulate it. Here it is with a watch.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.shouldBeDisabled = true;
  $scope.disabledText  = 'disabled stuff';

  $scope.maintainTrueValue = '';


  $scope.$watch('shouldBeDisabled', function() {

    if ($scope.shouldBeDisabled)
       $scope.maintainTrueValue = $scope.someValue;
    $scope.someValue= $scope.shouldBeDisabled && $scope.disabledText || $scope.maintainTrueValue;

  }); 


  $scope.toggleIt = function() {
      $scope.shouldBeDisabled= ! $scope.shouldBeDisabled;
  }

});
```

Demo with watch:   http://plnkr.co/edit/8KAJc9JXvi2rffsjPXF5?p=preview

Comment: I am accepting  this one, because it does not require duplication of elements.

Comment: Thanks.  Alternatively you could overlay a span/div over the input when it is disabled and display the disabled text in that but it is pretty simple via javascript or with two inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ng-show/ng-hide to swap out the input like so:

```
<input ng-model="disabledText" ng-show="shouldBeDisabled" disabled/>
<input ng-model="someValue" ng-hide="shouldBeDisabled"/>
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SVxCe/